# Node.js and MySQL. forEach() inside Promise - last item is not being inserted in array

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, foreach, promise

I'm having trouble pushing the last element of a query inside an array.

- The program should loop through the `testArray` and search inside the database for the corresponding `MedikamentId`
- and then create an array of those IDs.

This almost works and the output currently looks like this: `[3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3]`

But the last element is missing, there should also be a `2` at the end of this array (in sum there must be 14 elements).

When I run the `console.log(medIdArray)` which is commented inside the loop I get the correct array.

Why is my last item not being returned when I put the `medIdArray` inside the `.then()` handler?

```js
let testArray = [
  ['Pantoprazol','Ibuprofen'],
  ['Pantoprazol','Ibuprofen'],
  ['Pantoprazol','Ibuprofen'],
  ['Pantoprazol','Ibuprofen'],
  ['Pantoprazol','Ibuprofen'],
  ['Pantoprazol','Ibuprofen'],
  ['Pantoprazol','Ibuprofen'],
];

let medIdArray = [];
let sqlGetMedId = "SELECT MedikamentId FROM Medikament WHERE Bezeichnung = ?";
let getMedId = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  testArray.forEach((i, idx, array) => {
    i.forEach((j) => {
      mySqlConnection.query(sqlGetMedId, j, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        medIdArray.push(rows[0].MedikamentId);
        //console.log(medIdArray);
        if (idx === array.length-1) resolve();
      })
    })
  })
})

getMedId.then(() => {
  console.log(medIdArray);
})

getMedId.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code

```
if (idx === array.length-1) resolve();
```

resolves the promise at the *first* iteration for the inner loop instead of the second. Use

```
i.forEach((j, idx2) => {
   ...
   if (idx === array.length-1 && idx2 === i.length -1) resolve();
}
```

or something similar ...

**EDIT**

But instead of nesting loops you proably could flatten your input array first and that iterate over the flattened array

```
let testArray = [[..], [..]];
let flattened = testArray.reduce((a, c) => {
  a.push(...c);
  return a;
}, [])

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   flattened.forEach((elem, idx) => {
     con.query(..., (err, rows, fields) => {
       ...
       if (idx === flattened.length - 1) resolve();
     });
   });
});
```

or you could also use `Promise.all`

```
let getIds = Promise.all(flattened.map(med => new Promise((res, rej) => { 
  conn.query(..., med, (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (err) rej(err);
    res(rows[0].MedikamentId);
  });
})));

getIds.then(data => {
  //data is an array of query results 
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for your suggested answers. The idea with flattening the input array is good. To better understand the code I'm working on I took the first suggestion and it worked fine for me.

Comment: You actually *should* use the `Promise.all()` solution. Due to the asynchronicity of `mySqlConnection.query()`, the order in which results arrive is arbitrary and the last result received will not necessarily correspond to the last query made. Therefore `if (idx === flattened.length - 1) resolve()` may well fire early and the promise will get resolved before all the results have arrived. The problem can be overcome by keeping a count of results (and writing the test accordingly) but why go to the trouble when `Promise.all()` does all that for you?